# how to do query nested object using jpa

Tags: hibernate, jpa, nested

Suppose I have two object Patient and its MedicalRecord with OneToMany relation.

i.e.

```
class Patient {
    ...
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "patient")
    List<MedicalRecord> mr;
    ...
}

class MedicalRecord {
    ...
    @ManyToOne
    Patient patient;

    Date createdAt;
    ...
}
```

Now I want to work with the MedicalRecord(s) within one month. What is the best way to do this?

I know i could do it using JPQL with @NamedQuery or @Query. But I don't feel it's as good as I expected. Can I do this without issuing JPQL query and stay in the object domain? For example to add constraint on the "Patient.mr" field so that only records within one month will be retrieved and I can iterate through them without worrying about unnecessary database fetch?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can utilize Hibernate [filters](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/manual/en-US/html/ch19.html) for this purpose.

Assuming there is `RECORD_DATE` column in the table to which `MedicalRecord` is mapped, you can define a filter like `RECORD_DATE >= SYSDATE - 30` for the `mr` collection.

Answer (score 4):

This enum includes the date ranges:

```
public enum DateType {

    PAST_DAY,

    PAST_WEEK,

    PAST_MONTH, 

    PAST_YEAR 
}
```

**This Query:**

```
interface MedicalRecordRepository extends JpaRepository<MedicalRecord, Long> {
   @Query("select md from MedicalRecord md left join fetch md.patient pt   where md.createdAt >=:selectedDate")
   List<MedicalRecord> searchByDate(selectedDate);
}
```

Impletation Class:

```
     @Service
     class  MedicalRecordServiceImpl implements MedicalRecordService{

      public  List<MedicalRecord> searchByDate(DateType dateType){
            Date today = new Date();
            Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
            cal.setTime(today);

            switch (dateType) {
            case PAST_DAY:
                cal.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);
                break;
            case PAST_WEEK:
                cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, -1);
             break;
            case PAST_MONTH:
                cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -1);
                break;
            case PAST_YEAR:
                cal.add(Calendar.YEAR, -1);
                break;
            }
            List<MedicalRecord> result = repository.searchByDate(cal.getTime());
            return result;
       }
 }
```

Returns results based on your choice of date.